# How does linking within a webpage work?

Tags: html

I know that linking in general looks like

```
<a href="examplesite.com"> examplesite.com  </a>
```

I was wondering how would someone link within the page it self. Sort of like when someone clicks on biography section in Wikipedia and it scrolls down to the part that has the biography but staying on the same page.

Any example could would be great.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you're referring to URL fragments (a.k.a. named anchors or bookmark links).

You'd create such a link like:

```
<a href="#example">Jump to example</a>
```

Which would take you to the part of the page where the element with the ID of `example` exists. Like:

```
<h1 id="example">example</h1>
```

In [older versions of HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html), the name attribute was first used for this, however the ID has replaced that.

Comment: @Pam - Why did you unaccept my answer for one that is only a link to a non-authoritative source?

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is actually a link inside a website. It does not contain a protocol such as `http://` nor starts with `//` which would indicate a protocol-relative link, so it would load `exampleside.com` relative to whatever path you are currently on.

These are the kind of links you can use (each inside `href="..."`). We assume that you are currently on `http://example.net/foo/index.html`

- `https://example.com` - goes to the "external" site `https://example.com`
- `//example.com` - goes to the "external" site `xxx://example.com` with `xxx` being the protocol used to load `example.net`, so in my example `http://example.com`
- `www.example.com` - goes to `http://example.net/foo/www.example.com` as it is not an external link
- `#foo` - goes to the element with `id="foo"` on the current site (does not load anything from the server)

---

So what you want is probably the last example: `<a href="#foo">...</a>` and then `id="foo"` on the element you want to jump to.

Answer (score 0):

Add some `id` to the element you want to link to, e.g

```
<div id="target">Hello</div>
```

Then you can link it by using `#`:

```
<a href="#target">Go to target</a>
```

```html
<a href="#target">Go to target</a>
<hr style="height: 300vh" />
<div id="target">Hello</div>
```